# How do i add a query string to $GET function

Tags: php, parameters, get

I have $GET function that by default send out a request to get 30 items back

```
$transactions = $MK->getTransactions($_GET)
```

It will go to the header as following

```
transactions?&page=1&per_page=30
```

And from the API provider module i found this line

```
 if (!empty($params['per_page'])) {
            $request_params['per_page'] = (int) $params['per_page'];
        }
```

SO my question is how to add the param to the $_GET

Right now when it goes out just as `$transactions = $MK->getTransactions($_GET)`

the request itself will go out as `/transactions?&page=1&per_page=30`

But i need to change the per_page value to smth else.

Comment: How to add what parameter? What result do you want? It's unclear.

Comment: `$_GET['per_page'] = 12345;` …?

Comment: @CBroe for some reason that does not work

Comment: And that does not work for us, as an actual problem description. You need to do a bit better in describing what the actual issue here is, if you want help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have smth like:

```
$transactions = $MK->getTransactions($_GET)
```

Whiich leads you to the following path:

```
/transactions?&page=1&per_page=30
```

But you want to change the value of one parameter in $_GET?

First, from you example, if you'd print $_GET, you would see:

```
Array
(
    [page] => 1
    [per_page] => 30
)
```

So do smth like:

```
$parameters = $_GET;
$parameters["per_page"] = 123;
```

And than:

```
$transactions = $MK->getTransactions($parameters);
```

which will result in changed number per page.